# Controller in magento2?

Tags: blocks, magento2.2, controllers, phtml, php-7

I have created a custom module.

and I want on Save

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() . 'sales/order/view'; ?> " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

On button click the form should call controller in which I can handle all posted data.

I have tried call controller using basepath, but it always redirect me to admin dashboard.
**Update:**

```
class Comment extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info 
{ 

/** 
* Core registry 
* 
* @var \Magento\Framework\Registry 
*/ 
protected $coreRegistry = null; 

public function __construct( 
FormKey $formKey, \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, 
\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry, 
\Magento\Sales\Helper\Admin $adminHelper, 
\Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository, 
\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface $metadata, 
\Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\ElementFactory $elementFactory, 
\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer, 
array $data = [] 
) 
{ 
$this->coreRegistry = $registry; 
$this->formkey = $formKey; 
$this->_isScopePrivate = true; 
$this->_template = 'order/view/comment.phtml'; 
parent::__construct($context,$registry,$adminHelper, $groupRepository,$metadata,$elementFactory, $addressRenderer,$data); 
} 

public function getFormKey() 
{ 
return $this->formkey->getFormKey(); 
} 

public function getCurrentOrder(): Order 
{ 
return $this->coreRegistry->registry('current_order'); 
}

public function getOrderComment(): string
{
    return trim($this->getCurrentOrder()->getData(OrderComment::COMMENT_FIELD_NAME));
}
```

Comment: Please check update in chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `$block->getBaseUrl()` use `$block->getUrl()` to get the url and for the form submit you have to add formkey as a hidden input. try below solution.

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('*/*/view') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This will call current module's View controller if you want another `sales/order/view`  controller then use below action.

```
 <form action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('sales/order/view') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and after that add this hidden input in your form.

```
 <input name="form_key" value="<? echo $block->getFormKey()?>" type="hidden"/>
```

**Update**

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('*/*/view',['order_id'=>$your_order_id]) ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: its return "This order no longer exists" error

Comment: Do you want to edit particular order?

Comment: yes........edit custom input field in order

Comment: see my updated answer.

Comment: Can you please check if you get current order from registry?

Comment: Yes ...I can get current order @Rakesh

Comment: Update code in question

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: lets continue in chat

Comment: I got it.Thank U for ur response  @Rakesh